# Custom adapter in fragment listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to add a custom adapter to a listview within a fragment. It's running fine but it is not displaying anything in fragment. I've tried many methods but I am not able to get it to work. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:
**Fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/UniFeeList"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    >

</ListView>


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    android:id="@+id/addQuestion"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment.Java**

```
public class UniFeedFragment extends Fragment {
    ListView uniFeedListview;
    FloatingActionButton askQuestion;
    String stdEmail, UniEmail;
    TextView tv;
    Post post;
    String date,time;
    ListView UniFeedList;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup view =  (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.unifeedfragment, container, false);



        //Getting Time
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        time = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        //Getting Date
        DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date today = new Date();
        date = dateFormatter.format(today);

        //Getting data from news feed search bar
        UniFeed uniFeed = (UniFeed) getActivity();
        stdEmail = uniFeed.stdEmail;
        UniEmail = uniFeed.uni.getEmail();

        //Setting Listview
        UniFeedList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.UniFeeList);
        final ArrayList<Post> postArray = new ArrayList<Post>();
        PostListAdapter PostList = new PostListAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.activity_uni_feed ,postArray);
        UniFeedList.setAdapter(PostList);


        return view;
    }
```

**PostListAdapter.java**

```
public class PostListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context = null;
ArrayList<Post> postData = new ArrayList<>();
LayoutInflater inflater;

public PostListAdapter(Context context, int activity_uni_feed, ArrayList<Post> postData){
    this.context = context;
    this.postData = postData;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return postData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.unifeedpost, parent, false);

    return convertView;
} }
```

**unifeedPost.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/stdProfileImage"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Name"
    android:id="@+id/stdName"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/stdProfileImage"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stdProfileImage"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Date and Time"
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_below="@+id/stdName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stdProfileImage"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/stdProfileImage" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/postContent"
    android:layout_below="@id/time"
    android:text="Test Post"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stdProfileImage"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/postContent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/stdProfileImage"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Like"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comment"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I see your `postArray` doesn't contains any data so you `ListView` will have 0 item

Comment: I am using the following code to set data in getView() method:
       TextView Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stdName);
        TextView DateTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
  TextView postContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postContent);

        Name.setText(post.getStdName());
        DateTime.setText(post.getTime() + "  "+post.getDate());
        postContent.setText(post.getContent());

It's still not working

Comment: in your getView, you are returning a blank layout.